# How to fix the bug?

Tags: ios, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
  AES::~AES() in libusc.a(AES.o)
"___gxx_personality_sj0", referenced from:
  _decyptToken in libusc.a(tokenWrap.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I hava use a static library in my project,and the static library support armv7.

Comment: Did you include the "static library" in the build phase & import it in code?

Comment: Try linking against libc++.dylib.  This might not work, because this code might require GCC, while Xcode these days uses clang.  If you can get the source that would be an easier way to resolve this.

Comment: Also try linking against libstdc++.dylib instead.  This might solve the problem (This is GCC's C++ standard library)

Comment: I hava fixed the bug,just  modify the AppDelegate.m file suffix to .mm.